# Getting request with Http giving Result with WebSocket

Tags: http, websocket, crud

I try to make an architecture for my realtime app.

What i think is getting request with https(with server 1)  and sending result with ws(not wss - server 2) 
server 1 sending data to server 2 then server 2 will send to data directly to machine.

I dont want to use wss connection because sending data from websocket server with ws is not very important and critical. Can  be more faster? or i need to create a communication with directly wss ? Just i try to do is handling much more user at same time

Is it very illogical?